# Sort markers by type google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using the code from the followin link: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=nl

How can i sort the marker by type. I saw a piece of code that i can maybe use, but not sure how to use it. code: // bind handler to checkbox.
`document.getElementById('myCheckbox').onchange = onClickHandler;`

Someone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by putting an `order by` clause in the SQL statement, for example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers ORDER BY type";
```